# How to load images offline in volley.Does volley caches images automatically or there is a need to cache images?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley, offline-caching

when i am using thsi api:

```
private static final String JSON_URL = " https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/view-flipper/heroes.php";
```

image is showing when internet is disconnetd so there is no need of caching required;

I am retrieving like this in try block

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);    
JSONArray teamArray = obj.getJSONArray("heroes");
```

but when i am using this api:

```
private static final String JSON_URL = "   private static final String JSON_URL = "https://www.qasoftearth.com/images/team/team.json";
```

there is no json object so i am retrieving like this in try block and in this image is not loading when internet is disconnected:

```
JSONArray teamArray=new JSONArray(response);
```

so i wanna know is there any difference in api having json object and one having json array.Does Having json object caches your images automatically?

Below is my code,how to load images when internet is not there?

OurTeam.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import com.avi_qasoftearth.aviqasoft.Adapter.OurTeamViewPagerAdapter;
    import com.avi_qasoftearth.aviqasoft.DataModel.Hero;
    import com.avi_qasoftearth.aviqasoft.DataModel.Team;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator;

    public class OurTeam extends AppCompatActivity {

        ViewPager viewPager;
        List<Team> our_team;
        TextView tv1,tv2;

        LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
        int dotscount;
        ImageView[] dots;

        ArrayList<String>name_array= new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String>img_url_array=new ArrayList<>();

  private static final String JSON_URL = "https://www.qasoftearth.com/images/team/team.json";
   // private static final String JSON_URL = " https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/view-flipper/heroes.php";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_our_team);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.our_team_name_textView);
            tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.our_team_designation_textView);
            our_team=new ArrayList<>();
            loadTeam();


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            onBackPressed();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void loadTeam() {
            //getting the progressbar
            final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            //making the progressbar visible
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //creating a string request to send request to the url
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            //hiding the progressbar after completion
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            Log.d("hello", response.toString());
                            try {

                                JSONArray teamArray=new JSONArray(response);


                                //now looping through all the elements of the json array
                                for (int i = 0; i < teamArray.length(); i++)
                                {
                                    //getting the json object of the particular index inside the array
                                    JSONObject teamObject = teamArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Team movie = new Team();
                                    movie.setEmpName(teamObject.getString("EmpName"));
                                    movie.setPic(teamObject.getString("Pic"));
                                    movie.setPosition(teamObject.getString("Position"));
                                    movie.setEmail(teamObject.getString("Email"));
                                    movie.setPhone(teamObject.getString("Phone"));
                                    our_team.add(movie);

                                }


                              viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.our_team_viewpager);
                              CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                              OurTeamViewPagerAdapter o=new OurTeamViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),our_team);
                              viewPager.setAdapter(o);

                              indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);


                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                        {
                            //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });


            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


        }
    }
```

AppController.java

```
package com.avi_qasoftearth.aviqasoft;


import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static AppController mInstance;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

LruBitmapCache.java

```
package com.avi_qasoftearth.aviqasoft;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
        ImageLoader.ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use glide instead

```
RequestOptions options = new    RequestOptions() . centerCrop() ;
Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(options).into(imageView);
```

You can cache image by:

```
options.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
```

Comment: i am using this version : implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0' but still it doesn't load image from cache Glide.with(context_team).load(our_team_obj.getPic()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(imageView_team);

Comment: Try DiskCacheStrategy.ALL

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use picasso its too easy library for images and caches the images

```
      Picasso.with(context)
          .load("imgurl")
          .resize(80, 80)
          .error(R.drawable.user_dummy)
          .placeholder(R.drawable.user_dummy)
          .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I am already using picasso in viewpager adapter Picasso.with(context_team).load(our_team_obj.getPic()).into(imageView_team);

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference in JSON object and JSON Array in terms if you want to cache images.From a programmer point they are just String until they are parsed so Picasso just need the Image URL inside its load() to cache it.

Now in your case i have viewed your APIs

1. In your First API you are returning an object , In which images had a url with
   **https://**
2. In your Second API you are using **http://**

May be this is the reason why your images are not cached.

Comment: No , take a look at your Image URL for example http ://qasoftearth.com/images/team/abhishek.jpg its http://

Comment: Is your problem Solved ?